# React Native: Switch from createBottomTabNavigator to createMaterialBottomNavigator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am fully aware that using `createBottomTabNavigator` will give you a nice iOS bottom tabs with no background color while `createMaterialBottomNavigator` will give you a background color and different setup on android device.

My goal is to to use `createBottomTabNavigator` on iOs device and then switch to `createMaterialBottomNavigator` on android device with all the setup like putting activeTintColor color, using `shifting: true` mode whenever you switch screen on android.

So what I did is I use the Platform API:

```
const MealsFavTabNavigator =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? createMaterialBottomNavigator(navTabConfig)
        : createBottomTabNavigator();
```

And then, create a possible config:

```
const navTabConfig = {
    options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
        )
    }}
};
```

Then tried to switch this on my navigator:

```
 <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                name="Meals"
                component={MealsNavigator}
                navTabConfig
            />

Which did not work. Here's the full code:

    import React from 'react';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    
    import { Platform } from 'react-native';
    import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
    
    import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
    import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
    import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';
    
    import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';
    
    import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
    import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
    
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
    
    import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';
    
    import Colors from '../constants/colors';
    
    const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();
    
    const MealsNavigator = () => {
        return (
            <MealsNav.Navigator
                mode="modal"
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                    },
                    headerTintColor: '#fff',
                    headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontSize: 17
                    }
                }}
            >
                <MealsNav.Screen
                    name="Categories"
                    component={CategoriesScreen}
                    options={{
                        title: 'Meals Categories'
                    }}
    
                />
                <MealsNav.Screen
                    name="CategoryMeals"
                    component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                    options={({ route }) => {
                        const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                        const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);
    
                        return {
                            title: selectedCategory.title,
                        };
    
                    }}
                />
                <MealsNav.Screen
                    name="MealDetail"
                    component={MealDetailScreen}
                    options={{
                        title: 'Meal Detail',
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Favorite'
                                    iconName='ios-star'
                                    onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
            </MealsNav.Navigator>
        );
    };
    
    const MealsFavTabNavigator =
        Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? createMaterialBottomNavigator(navTabConfig)
            : createBottomTabNavigator();
    
    
    const navTabConfig = {
        options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
            )
        }}
    };
    
    
    const MealsTabNav = () => {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator
                    tabBarOptions={{
                        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                    }}>
                    <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                        name="Meals"
                        component={MealsNavigator}
                        navTabConfig
                    />
                    <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                        name="Favorites"
                        component={FavoritesScreen}
                        options={{
                            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                                <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                            )
                        }}
                    />
                </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    };
    
    
    export default MealsTabNav;
```

How can I attain my goal of switching from `createBottomTabNavigator` to `createMaterialBottomNavigator` and then applying the basic styles on `createMaterialBottomNavigator` such as `activeTintcolor` and `shifting` mode.

Please help! I am super stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct only little change that you need to do is the way you use the props.

The below code is a generic example, I'm not using your components

The tab creation is same but the when you get the props its better if you can use a function like below.
Here the function will return the props for the appropriate navigator and we use the spread operator to pass the props.
You can chose to do this only tabBarOptions but this example shows for all props which is more flexible.

```
const Tab = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator() : createBottomTabNavigator();

const getNavigationOptions = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    //Props for the ios navigator
    return {
      labeled: false,
      initialRouteName: 'Settings',
      activeColor: 'red',
      inactiveColor: 'white'
    };
  }
  //Props for any other OS navigator
  return {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    tabBarOptions: { activeTintColor: 'red' },
  };
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator {...getNavigationOptions()}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

To apply this to your project
//Keep this line as it is

```
const MealsFavTabNavigator =
        Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? createMaterialBottomNavigator()
            : createBottomTabNavigator();

<MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator {...getNavigationOptions()}>
```

And update the getNavigationOptions with your own probs based on the platform

Comment: Thank you but I am still a bit confuse on how to apply this to my own project.

Comment: Checking this now.

Comment: ios works ? icons are provided at screen level and its applicable for both navigators

Comment: I gave the sample for props at navigator level, you can use the same approach for screens as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218431/discussion-between-jones-smith-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Comment: Super smart guy

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: That is the basic setup. I am trying to switch from createBottomTabNavigator to createMaterialBottomNavigator on different device.